# Underlining Cell contents including leading blank spaces in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

Currently i'm generating a PDF using iTextSharp in ASP.Net.

One of a field of variable lenght needs to be underlined. Actually in the output file the particular field is shown with lines (as in a ruled notebook).

For example, the field has been allocated 10 lines, so that the user can fill-in depending upon the requirement he has or may be left blank.  But, now after automation, data will be fed by the user, which will be later generated as a PDF file, and this particular field is of variable length.

Is there a way i can underline the leading spaces of the field, say only 500 out of 1500 chars width is filled and rest 1000 chars can be underlined.  Is there any way i can achieve it with iTextSharp.

i tried it by appending underscores to the actual data (while retrieving it from DB) and underlining the text data by assigning the underline property to the chunk class, but didn't help.

Thanks for any pointers/advise/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Download http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf and take a look at the figures in section 2.2.6. Is that more or less what you're looking for? In that case, you need to use a `LineSeparator` as described in that section.